# mgcv: How to return estimated smoothing parameter?

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

Consider the simple GAM fit as below:

```
library(mgcv)
my.gam <- gam(y~s(x), data=mydata)
```

1. Is there anyway to return the estimated smoothing parameter (lambda) so that I can save it? I know that lambda is given in output as 'GCV score', but I need a specific code for returning it.
2. How can I set lambda to a desired value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`summary()` does not return smoothing parameters. You have mixed up GCV score with smoothing parameter. Consult a local statistician if you don't understand those concepts, or raise a question on Cross Validated. I will only show you how to extract and set smoothing parameters.

Consider an example:

```
library(mgcv)
set.seed(2)
dat <- gamSim(1, n=400, dist="normal", scale=2)
b <- gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), data=dat)
```

You can get **internal** smoothing parameters from:

```
b$sp
#       s(x0)        s(x1)        s(x2)        s(x3) 
#3.648590e+00 3.850127e+00 1.252710e-02 4.986399e+10
```

But these are not `lambda`. They differ from `lambda` by some positive scaling factors. It is usually sufficient to use `sp` for smoothing parameters. If you want to set it to a fixed value, do for example:

```
b1 <- gam(y ~ s(x0, sp = 0) + s(x1, sp = 0) + s(x2, sp = 0) + s(x3, sp = 0),
          data = dat)
```

This essentially disables penalization for all smooth terms. Note that setting `sp` to a negative value implies auto-selection of `sp`.

---

**`lambda` and `sp`**:

[image]

```
sapply(b$smooth, "[[", "S.scale") / b$sp
#       s(x0)        s(x1)        s(x2)        s(x3) 
#6.545005e+00 5.326938e+00 1.490702e+03 4.097379e-10
```

Sometimes getting `lambda` is necessary. When considering smooth functions as random effects or random fields, there is

```
variance_parameter_of_random_effect = scale_parameter / lambda
```

where the scale parameter can be found in `b$scale` (for Gaussian model this is also `b$sig2`). See a related question: [GAM with "gp" smoother: how to retrieve the variogram parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51658946/4891738)

---

**Follow-up**

> Yes, I need the exact value of `lambda`, so thanks for the neat code. Yet I'm interested in knowing more about the scaling factor. Where can I read more about it in addition to the package manual?

Have a read on `?smoothCon`:

```
smoothCon(object,data,knots=NULL,absorb.cons=FALSE,
          scale.penalty=TRUE,n=nrow(data),dataX=NULL,
          null.space.penalty=FALSE,sparse.cons=0,
          diagonal.penalty=FALSE,apply.by=TRUE,modCon=0)

scale.penalty: should the penalty coefficient matrix be scaled to have
          approximately the same 'size' as the inner product of the
          terms model matrix with itself? ...
```

In the source code of `smoothCon`, there is:

```
if (scale.penalty && length(sm$S) > 0 && is.null(sm$no.rescale)) {
    maXX <- norm(sm$X, type = "I")^2
    for (i in 1:length(sm$S)) {
        maS <- norm(sm$S[[i]])/maXX
        sm$S[[i]] <- sm$S[[i]]/maS
        sm$S.scale[i] <- maS
    }
}
```

Briefly speaking, for a model matrix `X` and raw penalty matrix `S`, scaling factor `maS` is:

```
norm(S) / norm(X, type = "I")^2
```

Comment: Maybe that makes a difference but I have something like this: `gam.out <-gam(y~s(x1, bs = "tp", k = 5) + (x2, bs = "tp", k = 5)+s(x1,x2, bs = "tp", k = 24)), data=data,select=TRUE, method="REML",family = poisson(link = "log"))` I guess 'select' is doing the 2X3 matrix.

Comment: @M.Beausoleil Oh, with "select", each `s()` has two smoothing parameters. My code will give you a vector of 6 values. You can of course reshape it to a matrix, using `matrix(results, nrow = 2, ncol = 3)`. So each column contains 2 smoothing parameters for an `s()` term. This is a good point. I should mention this in the answer. Thanks. Also, you are welcome to vote it up, if it has helped you. :D

Comment: What would be the meaning? In the end you'd have 6 different lambdas?

Comment: @M.Beausoleil For each `s()` under `select = TRUE`, the first smoothing parameter is to penalize curvature, the second is to penalize linear trend. `select = FALSE` only has the first one, which at most shrink the function to a linear line or bilinear plane; `select = TRUE` adds the second one, which can further shrink the line or plane to 0.

Comment: Also, in your example, is lambda computed like this: `scale.par = sapply(b$smooth, "[[", "S.scale") / b$species` and then `lambda = b$sp/scale.par` so the smallest lambda is  0.000008 and the largest is 2228963173967866624.00? (in your example)

Comment: @M.Beausoleil What is `b$species`? But .... oops, I did something wrong there... I should reverse the numerator and denominator. So (1) the scaling parameter `alpha` is `alpha <- sapply(b$smooth, "[[", "S.scale")`; (2) the correct code for getting `lambda` from `sp` is: `b$sp / alpha` (not `alpha / b$sp` in the answer). It will take bigger effort to revise this answer for better clarity. I should probably add more examples as well. I will definitely improve this answer when I am available. Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry, my computer corrected "sp" to "species"... That was my understanding also, that the denominator and numerator were reversed... also what is the reference for the image under the "lambda and sp:" section? I'm curious to read around this.

Comment: @M.Beausoleil I wrote the equation in the image, to explain the scaling that **mgcv** does under the hood. It is not to be found anywhere else. This is a low-level technical detail, and is not mentioned in the book *GAMs: and introduction with R*. It is only mentioned in package documentation `?smoothCon`, as I quoted in the answer.  The scaling is used to enhance numerical stability during computations.